# Python : Process calling GRPC server gets stuck and terminates unexpectedly

Tags: python, python-2.7, process, multiprocessing, grpc

I have one GRPC server running.
say: localhost, 46001

I have a python program which is creating a Process Pool of 4 processes. Here the Process Pool is custom:

```
Process_Pool(Process): have a process dict with 4 running process context.
```

I have maintained this process pool for my use case. **Note**: this functionality is working fine as i tested without GRPC involvement.

GRPC Client implementation is like:

```
class Client(object):

def __init__(self, host, port):
    self.host = host
    self.server_port = port
    self.channel = grpc.insecure_channel("{}:{}".format(self.host, self.server_port))
    self.stub = some_server_pb2_grpc.SomeInterfaceStub(self.channel)
```

Which is working fine when i run it from command line:

`python`

```
client = Client("localhost", 46001)
my_dict= {'timestamp': 1555421947, 'additional_info': {}}
client.set_status(my_dict)
```

The problem i am facing is, while creating a GRPC client call to server from those 4 processes like:

```
client = Client("localhost", 46001)
client.set_status(some_dict)
```

The process terminates itself unexpectedly. No logs gets printed further. I have handled every exception, even around the above code call.

My only inference till now is: GRPC does not work with newly spawned Processes.

Can anyone help me in solving this?

Answer (score 0):

gRPC Python client supports multi-processing with environment variable `GRPC_ENABLE_FORK_SUPPORT=1`.

However, the fork support story for gRPC Python server is more complicated (see https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/18321).

Comment: Hi Lidi, thanks for the suggestion. But it is not working either. The code still reaches till grpc client and do not reach server and the process calling this grpc client gets halted.

Comment: Hi rachitmanit@, sorry I wasn't check your environment first. Currently, the fork support only work: 1) Under Linux; 2) For polling strategy "select", "poll", "epoll1". If you are running your code under Windows and you really need this feature, please consider file an issue in https://github.com/grpc/grpc.

Comment: Hi Lidi, i tried the same on Debian (Linux) machine. It didn't work.